# Why is copying a linked list to a vector giving a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, linked-list, stl

```
int main() {
    LinkedList list;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        list.appendFront(i);

    vector<int> list_copy;
    Node *temp = list.head;
    int i = 0;
    while (temp->next)
    {
        list_copy[i] = temp->info; //segmentation fault at this line
        temp = temp->next;
        i++;
    }

    for (auto i : list_copy)
        cout << i;
}
```

Please note that I am using my implementation of Linked List and it works fine.

Comment: should be `while (temp)` and `push_back`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vector<int> list_copy;
```

The initializationn of your vector is an empty initialization.

So your vector is empty but you try to acces non-existed element, hence segmentation fault.

To avoid that change the initialiation to make the vector of size equal to your list size (which is 6 as I see).

```
vector<int> list_copy(6);
```

Or you can use `push_back()` but the first method is more efficient to avoid reallocation.

Answer (score 0):

at this line

```
list_copy[i]
```

there are no values in the vector. Adding an entry to the vector is done by

```
list_copy.push_back(temp->info);
```

Edit:

A revised method could be:

```
int main() {
    LinkedList list;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        list.appendFront(i);

    vector<int> list_copy;
    Node *temp = list.head;
    while (temp) // ensure the current record isn't null
    {
        list_copy.push(temp->info);
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    for (auto i : list_copy)
        cout << i;
}
```